# How to add table title in python preferably with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add a table title in the out put. It's relatively easy to do this in `r` with
`flextable`, you just have to use function `set_caption()`, is there a similar package in `python` with `pandas` dataframe (maybe `PTable`)?

This is what I have right now,
[image: pic1]

and this is what I would like to have
[image: pic2]

Please help, thanks guys!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Have you tried this doing this?

```
df.style.set_caption("Hello World")
```

Source: [Pandas Styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

EDIT:

Here's an alternative way to present your table if you're okay with using `matplotlib`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

my_frame = pd.DataFrame(data={'simulation1':[71,4.8,65,4.7],
                              'simulation2':[71,4.8,69,4.7],
                              'simulation3':[70,3.8,68,4.9],
                              'experiment':[70.3,3.5,65,4.4]})
#my_frame Display pandas table

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8, 2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.table(cellText = my_frame.values,
          rowLabels = my_frame.index,
          colLabels = my_frame.columns,
          loc = "center"
         )
ax.set_title("Top 10 Fields of Research by Aggregated Funding Amount")

ax.axis("off");
```

Comment: It should be working from what I read, but it's giving me this ```OptionError: "No such keys(s): 'display.precision'"``` error

Comment: Is your pandas library up to date? I tried searching for the error message you encountered and majority of the suggestions were to update pandas

Comment: I have a numerical table - when I add set caption it adds .00000 zeros to each value. How to remove them?

Comment: I am lost, does `df.style.set_caption("Hello World")` add a title to a table? Any requirement for it to work?

Comment: To clarify pandas styling confusion (cf. a few comments in different As here), operations on `pd.DataFrame().style` are *not* in place on the `style` dynamic attribute of `df.DataFrame`, but these returns a `pd.io.formats.style.Styler`, which when passed to `IPython.display.display` renders like a `pd.DataFrame`, but is not a `pd.DataFrame`.

Answer (score 22):

It appears this does not set the caption 'inplace', like:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

is the same as:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Instead try:

```
df = df.style.set_caption('Top 10 Fields of Research by Aggregated Funding Amount')
```

Answer (score 8):

```py
styles = [dict(selector="caption",
                       props=[("text-align", "center"),
                              ("font-size", "150%"),
                              ("color", 'black')])]

df = df.style.set_caption("funcioasadsaaaa").set_table_styles(styles)

df
```

Comment: Suppose you want more than one sentence as title, the second sentence being below the first sentence, the third below the second, etc? like in name of university, below it name of department.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
df.style.set_table_attributes("style='display:inline'").set_caption('Caption table')
```

The output, with the title (hi-lighted in yellow) that will be displayed, is shown below

[image]

Comment: Didn't work. Might be valuable to indicate where this should be added or if there are any other imports required for this to work. A full example would go a long way.

Comment: May I know how your are trying? i just uploaded the screenshot of Juypter notebook.
I guess your are trying on Ipython on command line where it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
df.style.set_caption('Top 10 Fields of Research by Aggregated Funding Amount')
```

Comment: didn't work. Perhaps you need to elaborate with more of a df setup.