# Add Title to Dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do a calendar using pandas dataframes. The problem is I can't find the way to put a title on each dataframe.

This is my code for the "January" dataframe. What I want is to add the title "January".

```
import pandas as pd
January= [['','','','','',1 ,2],[t for t in range(3,10)],[t for t in range(10,17)],[t for t in range(17,24)],
         [t for t in range(24,31)],[31,'','','','','','']]

df = pd.DataFrame(January, columns=['Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa','So'])
df.style.hide_index().set_table_styles([{'selector' : '','props' : [('border','1px solid black')]}])
```

I've been searching for a while and haven't found or understood any solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add table title in python preferably with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57958432/how-to-add-table-title-in-python-preferably-with-pandas)

Comment: It does something, although it doesn't really look like a title. But if there isn't something better I'll take it. Thank you